# Name error with Tkinter get() widget and global variables

Tags: python, global-variables, tkinter-entry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIBXf.png)What I want to do is get user to input 4 values to entry widgets and after and using those input values or function returns in another function but I get name error. I tried to turn the entry variables into global because but it still gives name error. My code below is like a summary and I am a beginner so can anyone help?

### This is the error:

---> 96     user_input = {'SKU':sku, 'From Company Descp.':SupplyOrigin, 'To Company Descp.':FinalLocation , 'Incoterms':Incoterm}
97     inputDf = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(user_input)).T
98     #inputDf = pd.DataFrame(user_input)

NameError: name 'sku' is not defined

```
***CODE HERE***
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
    import pandas as pd
    from tkinter import *

# initalise the tkinter GUI
root = tk.Tk()

#creating entry widgets for all 4 input areas that I want to get from the user
frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="User Input") #second frame will be used to put the entry widgets inside it
frame2.place(height=120, width=600, rely=0.75, relx=0.01)

canvas1=tk.Canvas(frame2, height=100, width=600) #create a canvas to inside the frame
entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
canvas1.create_window(60,50, window=entry1)
canvas1.pack()
label1 = tk.Label(frame2, text= "Enter SKU:", bg="purple", fg="white")
label1.place(rely=0.1,relx=0.0)

entry2 = tk.Entry(root) #creating a new entry for supply origin
canvas1.create_window(200, 50, window=entry2)
label2 =tk.Label(frame2, text= "Supply Origin Country:", bg="purple", fg="white")
label2.place(rely=0.1,relx=0.23)

entry3 = tk.Entry(root) #creating a new entry for final location
canvas1.create_window(340, 50, window=entry3)
label3 =tk.Label(frame2, text= "Final Location Country:", bg="purple", fg="white")
label3.place(rely=0.1,relx=0.47)


entry4 = tk.Entry(root) #creating a new entry for incoterm
canvas1.create_window(480, 50, window=entry4)
label4 =tk.Label(frame2, text= "Incoterm:", bg="purple", fg="white")
label4.place(rely=0.1,relx=0.7)

#Here I defined four functions to get inputs from user and I wanted to use the return values inside another function

def SKU():
    global sku
    sku = entry1.get() #get sku number 
    return sku

def Supply_Origin():
    global SupplyOrigin
    SupplyOrigin =entry2.get()
    return SupplyOrigin


def Final_Location():
    global FinalLocation
    FinalLocation = entry3.get()
    return FinalLocation


def Inc():
    global Incoterm
    Incoterm = entry4.get()
    return Incoterm
    #Inc = entry4.get() #get incoterm
    #Incoterm = []
    #Incoterm.append(Inc)

def user_input_calculator():
"I want to use global variables or above function return values in here"
    user_input = {'SKU':sku, :SupplyOrigin,'To Company Descp.':FinalLocation, 'To Company Descp.':FinalLocation , 'Incoterms':Incoterm}
    inputDf = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(user_input)).T
    return inputDf
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Your current code isn't runnable because `frame2` is never defined and you have a syntax error in the `user_input_calculator` function.

Comment: Hi there @peter frame2 is defined I mistakenly did not add that part of the code sorry for  that but I dont understand why I get this name error.

Comment: You still have the syntax error at the bottom. When I fix it and run your code I don't get your error at all. Please include a [mcve] so your error becomes reproducible.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the comments guys! Like you suggested I was able to get to the root of the problem and realized I needed an entirely different approach and got rid of all my global variables and seperate functions. Instead I created one function that has 4 entries under a class and I used the Prompt() attribute to use those values later on in another function. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *


# initalise the tkinter GUI
root = tk.Tk()

#forming the frame beforehand
frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="User Input") #second frame will be used to put the entry widgets inside it
frame2.place(height=120, width=600, rely=0.75, relx=0.01)

canvas1=tk.Canvas(frame2, height=100, width=600) #create a canvas to inside the frame
entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
canvas1.create_window(60,50, window=entry1)
canvas1.pack()
label1 = tk.Label(frame2, text= "Enter SKU:", bg="purple", fg="white")
label1.place(rely=0.1,relx=0.0)

entry2 = tk.Entry(root) #creating a new entry for supply origin
canvas1.create_window(200, 50, window=entry2)
label2 =tk.Label(frame2, text= "Supply Origin Country:", bg="purple", 
fg="white")
label2.place(rely=0.1,relx=0.23)

entry3 = tk.Entry(root) #creating a new entry for final location
canvas1.create_window(340, 50, window=entry3)
label3 =tk.Label(frame2, text= "Final Location Country:", bg="purple", 
fg="white")
label3.place(rely=0.1,relx=0.47)


entry4 = tk.Entry(root) #creating a new entry for incoterm
canvas1.create_window(480, 50, window=entry4)
label4 =tk.Label(frame2, text= "Incoterm:", bg="purple", fg="white")
label4.place(rely=0.1,relx=0.7)

button5 = tk.Button(frame2, text='Load input', command=prompt.user_input, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
button5.place(rely=0.50, relx=0.15)
canvas1.create_window(60, 80, window=button5)

class Prompt:
    def user_input(self):
        self.a = entry1.get() #these are the variables that I will use in user_input_calculator function later on using prompt attribute
        self.b = entry2.get()
        self.c = entry3.get()
        self.d = entry4.get()
        
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.btn = tk.Button(root, text="Get your input", command=self.user_input)
        self.btn.place(rely=0.50, relx=0.40)
        self.btn.pack()
prompt = Prompt(root)


def user_input_calculator():

user_input = {'SKU':prompt.a, 'From Company Descp.':prompt.b, 'To Company Descp.':prompt.c , 'Incoterms':prompt.d}
    inputDf = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(user_input)).T
    return inputDf
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not OK to mark as solved your own question based in the feedback of the comunity. You should had marked as solved the answer that has inspired you to fix your coding problems.